# Get a specific object in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I want to get only one element in a JSON object, from Django Rest Framework.

I got the next code Serializer:

```
class OneUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Usuario
        fields = ('usuario', 'nombre', 'apellidos', 'mensajes')
```

The View Set:

```
class OneUserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Usuario.objects.filter(id = 'Here is the PARAMETER')
    serializer_class = OneUserSerializer
```

The url:

```
router.register(r'user', views.OneUserViewSet)
```

I want to get only one object 'Usuario' passing the id from the url for example url/id_user

Answer (score 3):

If you're using `SimpleRouter`, then urls will be generated for you:

```
class OneUserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Usuario.objects.all()
    serializer_class = OneUserSerializer
```

urls.py

```
from rest_framework import routers

router = routers.SimpleRouter()
router.register(r'user', views.OneUserViewSet)
urlpatterns = router.urls
```

This will generate the following url (among others):

```
^users/{pk}/$
```